# Get a pointer to Object from std::vector<Object> in range-based for loop

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have a vector of objects - `journal`:

```
    std::vector<Object> journal;
    std::vector<Object*> filteredJournal;
    for (const auto &element : journal) {
            if (element.data[1] == user) {
                filteredJournal.push_back(&element);
            }
    }
```

I want to fill the vector of pointers to these objects, `filteredJournal`, with pointers to specific objects from `journal`. I tried to use `&` on `element`, but of course it gives me an error that I'm giving a wrong argument for `push_back()` function. What's is the right way to do that?

Comment: More interesting question than solving your _constness_ problem is, what do you want to do with that vector? You are aware it's unstable data?

Comment: It's potentially safe if you "constify" your vector after filling it, which is actually a viable design in many problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
const auto &element : journal
```

You bind a const reference to each element. So when you use it to take an address, you get a pointer to a const element. And you can't pass it to a function that expects a pointer to an object that is not const-qualified.

Just remove the const qualifier:

```
auto &element : journal
```

---

The usual caveats about iterator, reference and pointer invalidation apply of course. Make sure the `filteredJournal` doesn't last longer than the time span in which its pointers are guaranteed to be pointing at valid objects.

Comment: Maybe should be added that storing pointers to elements in a vector is usually not very good idea.

Comment: @super  Well, I actually have a very big amount of these objects, so that's why I'm not copying them to the `filteredJournal` and want to use pointers. Are there any better ways to keep info about a big amount of these objects without actually copying them and without using pointers?

Comment: @super - There's no problem to store non-owning pointers for a reasonable duration. Nothing in the OP's post suggested they do otherwise.

Comment: @StoryTeller Sure, but for beginners finding this post, a couple of lines informing that pointers could get invalidated if used incorrectly would still be a valuable addition IMO.

Comment: @StoryTeller But the pointers can easily become invalidated if `journal`'s capacity increases. Storing indices might be a safer bet.

Comment: @juanchopanza - It might, or it might be impossible, depending on whatever further processing those pointers are needed for.